# SQlite query returning zero results

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor, selection

My query with argument like /sdcard/Shri Ramachandra Bhajana.mp3 as a selection condition for the query

> "SELECT start,end FROM crop_list WHERE name ="+"trim('argument')"

but its returning 0 rows in the cursor.Although there are many entries in the database table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change to:

```
"SELECT start,end FROM crop_list WHERE name = '"+ argument.trim() + "'"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
"SELECT start,end FROM crop_list WHERE name = trim('"<argument>"')"
```

where `argument` is your string.

Answer (score 1):

Change your query to

```
SELECT start, end FROM crop_list WHERE name = trim('" + argument+"')
```

where your argument is

```
String argument = "/sdcard/Shri Ramachandra Bhajana.mp3";
```